# Virtual scroller and alphabetic search functionality issue

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

*.html*

```
<div>

  <span button="true" *ngFor="let al of alphabeticalList" 
    (click)="goToAlphabetCharacter(al)">

    {{al}}

  </span>

</div>

<ion-list>

    <div *ngFor="let keyBrand of (keyBrands$ |async)">

      <div id={{keyBrand?.key}}>
        {{keyBrand?.key}}
      </div>

      <app-brand *ngFor="let b of keyBrand?.brands" [brand]="b"></app-brand>

    </div>

  </ion-list>
```

*.ts*

```
goToAlphabetCharacter(character: string): void {

    const element: HTMLElement = document.getElementById(character);
    element.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'start', inline: 'nearest' });
  }
```

[image]

I have a technical problem here. The above code is working fine. But due to it has around 500 records it is almost nonresponsive. Due to that, I have to use a Virtual scroller here. Then the problem here is how can I use the alphabetic search functionality? Because the Virtual scroller shows a small chunk of data where it is for the visible screen. That means if say user clicked the `Z` on the above kind of view then no data to show there. So how to overcome this issue?

Comment: Virtual scroll usually means rendering only a few items inside and close to the visible area, and replacing the rest with a simple element (like a div), but settings its height to be equal to the height of the elements which are not rendered (so the scroll position always makes sense). When the user types "Z", you will need to calculate its offset from the top and scroll the view accordingly. The scroll should trigger a re-render method which calculates which set of items should be visible now, and how tall the upper and lower padded divs need to be to fill in the space of missing items.

Comment: @LazarLjubenović Sorry, I didn't get you. Can I have pseudo kind of code to show your technique here. You can use this https://github.com/rintoj/ngx-virtual-scroller#readme or else. I just need to get the idea only.